# Hide Bootstrap modal in mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, bootstrap-modal

How do I hide Bootstrap modal in *mobile*. I tried to use modifier classes such as *hidden-xs* *hidden-sm* but fail. The modal would go to the bottom page, leaving the top page inaccessible.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="modal fade hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top:1em;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-body">
       <img src="banner.jpg" height="388" width="558" alt="" class="img-rounded">
     </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" style="border:0">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since *hidden-xs* and *hidden-sm* fail, I tried to change my css:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
  #myModal{display: none;}
}
```

or

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
  .modal{display: none;}
}
```

but, they're also fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your media query is overwritten by jQuery. Try it with jQuery.

something like this:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    var width = $(window).width();  
    if(width < 480){
        $(this).hide(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I try it in desktop first, and the modal fails to show.

Comment: did you removed your old css lines?

Comment: Yes, I did. It was the example from Bootstrap manual:

     $(function() {
       $("#myModal").modal();
     });

Comment: Your code is working now, I modified .modal class in my styles, it prevent this code to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as you said that your css is not working i would recommend using jquery method just add this before the modal html code `<div class='check-width'>`, and use the below script.

```
if($('.check-width').width() == 500){
   $('#myModal').modal('hide'); 

}
else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Danko's answer above still left the darkened overlay on my page (even though no modal appeared) but this is what worked for me:

```
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        var width = $(window).width();  
        if(width < 768){
            $('#myModal').modal('hide') 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This media query did the trick for me.

```
    @media(max-width:810px){
    #mymodal{
        display: none !important;
    }

    .modal-backdrop{
        display: none !important;;
    }
}
```