# How to hide bootstrap modal in mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is the code. Tried to use hidden-xs, but that does not work on modal, get the screen darkened view on mobile. Any help would be appreciated here. Have tried using the hidden-xs, and removing fade, both did not work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Auto Loading Bootstrap Modal on Page Load</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    TEST
    <div class="hidden-md hidden-xs">
        This is a test page..1
    </div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade active">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Subscribe our Newsletter</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Subscribe to our mailing list to get the latest updates straight in your inbox.</p>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide Bootsrap modal in mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584172/hide-bootsrap-modal-in-mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mediaquery we can hide the modal according to screen width. Here i am using CSS Media to hide the modal when the screen width is upto 598px(mobiles,tablets). If screen width is more than 598 px (desktop,laptop) then the modal will display.

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Example of Auto Loading Bootstrap Modal on Page Load</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">/script><script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});</script><style>@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
.screen {
    display:none;}}@media only screen and (min-width: 599px) {
.screen {
    display:block;}}</style></head><body>
TEST
<div class="hidden-md hidden-xs screen">
    This is a test page..1
</div><div id="myModal" class="modal fade active screen">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Subscribe our Newsletter</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Subscribe to our mailing list to get the latest updates straight in your inbox.</p>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: if screen width is lessthan 599px the modal not visible  check this link this one working  codepen.io/Ramachandra/pen/MyVMEO

Answer (score 0):

This might be obsolete but you might find it useful in your case. Check if the user is browsing through mobile and if yes, do not show the `modal`.

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};

 $(document).ready(function(){
      if(!isMobile.any() ) { //check if it is not mobile
          $("#myModal").modal('show');
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hidden-xs` on the modal, and a CSS media query to hide the backdrop.

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
  .modal-backdrop{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/tBIIZce0l1

Answer (score 0):

I leveraged bootstrap's `.hidden-md-up` class, which hides an element for tablets, laptops, desktops, etc.

[Bootstrap v4 responsive utilities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
$(window).on("load resize",function(){
  if ($(window).width() >= 768) {  
    $('YOURSELECTOR').addClass('myModal');
  }
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $('.YOURSELECTOR').removeClass('myModal');
  }
});
```